# Unable to optimize the sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run the below query but it is taking a lot of time(more than 10 minutes). I have even created indexes on the columns in the where clause but it did not improve the performance of the query(it is still taking more than 10 min)

```
select count(1)
from customer_table ct,
     source_customer_table sc,
     customer_contact_table cc 
where sc.customer_ref = ct.customer_ref
  and sc.id = cc.contact_id
  and ct.contact_seq != cc.contact_sequence
```

The source_customer_table has approximately 200k rows whereas the customer_table and customer_contact_table have 150K rows.

In source_customer_table and customer_table , customer_ref is primary key.
In all the remaining columns , the values vary from 1 to 10.

I have created indexes this way:

```
   create index idx1 on source_customer_table(id) tablespace mig_idx;
   create index idx2 on customer_contact_table(contact_id) tablespace mig_idx;
   create index idx3 on customer_table(contact_seq) tablespace mig_idx; 
   create index idx4 on customer_contact_table(contact_sequence) tablespace mig_idx;
```

mig_idx is the tablespace specially created for indexes

Comment: How big tables? What's the result?

Comment: what about indexes? can you provide list of indexes for the tables?

Comment: Are you sure that the query is running on index in every join?

Comment: **Edit** your question and add the definitions of all indexes of the tables and the execution plan (as *formatted* text please)

Comment: Not directly related, but `count(1)` is not faster than `count(*)`.  It implies the query was built using old myths.

Comment: locking? are you running this on a live system or is it slow when you are alone in the database also?

Comment: @DanielStackenland: that's a select statement (without an "for update clause"), there can't be any locking involved.

Comment: I am sorry , I am unable to provide the explain plan as I am not at my workplace  right now

Comment: some proper explicit JOIN may help a bit the parsing engine

Comment: @Blag Although the explicit join syntax is more clear it won't improve performance in Oracle.  It may even decrease performance in a few rare cases because Oracle natively uses the old-fashioned syntax for the optimizer.

Comment: @JonHeller I was thinking more for `RIGHT` / `LEFT` / `INNER` that may help the optimizer to don't have to make double check. but yes, I know it'll not be a big improvement.

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name I'm not into oracle, but I'd guess that even in oracle a select-statement can be held waiting for some other query that's locking,